# Special character coming parsing the xml

Tags: android, xmlpullparser, good-dynamics

When I am parsing xml, I am getting special in good dynamics application char like that

pic.png

but the actual text is like that "If you've got any question or need"

[image]

But when I am parsing same text in normal application its working fine.

I am using sharepoint server to get xml. Now I am using general encoding UTF-8 only.

For parsing I am using XMLpullparser.

So how to resolve special character from xml.

Answer (score 0):

There might be two things you might check:

1. Persister class used to parse the .xml can be initialised with such constructor:

   ```
   Persister persister = new Persister(new Format(4, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?>"));
   ```
2. You might replace all such characters while parsing:

   ```
   value = value.replace("'", "\\'");
   ```